# Can not reduce size of an inserted image in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have done `Insert |Image Gallery` and cut and paste a single Image. I can only reduce its size a certain amount: it is still much too large.

[image]

- It is strange to do `Image Gallery` for a single image: is there another/better way?
- Why is it restricted from reducing the image size further?

Comment: How big is image in pixels?  You could open image in Preview and reduce its size then save it and use it in numbers.

Comment: I did reduce the image in Preview: it still has the same minimum dimensions in Numbers. Just bizarre

Comment: what happens if you reduce image size in Preview to less than the minimum size you see in Numbers..?

Comment: yea i had tried that. It just inserts a low resolution pixelated version. Super helpful of Preview there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Gallery is a special tool that allows more than one image to occupy the same space while allowing the user to view all of those images one by one. An image inserted via the Image Gallery into Numbers can not be edited as freely as other images. See [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eBu9rj2UnQ) if you wish to learn more about how to better use Image Gallery (the video is for Image Gallery in Pages but its functionality is the same in Numbers.)

If you simply want to use a picture in a Numbers table resizing it freely, either copy and paste it from Finder or click on the **Media** on the toolbar at the top of Numbers and then click on **Choose** and then find and select the picture you wish to insert.

You can also drag and drop any compatible picture from Finder into a Numbers cell and Numbers will automatically resize the picture to fit the cell that it is dragged into.

Comment: ah just cut and paste directly.